# WinForm Bottom Margin Property Doesn't Do Anything

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am new to WinForms, and I am very used to styling in CSS, so maybe I am not looking at WinForm's Bottom Margin property correctly, but, no matter what element I set an arbitrarily large bottom-margin number to, it seems to have no effect, at all.

What I want is to extend the design of the form to below the initial viewable window (vertical-scroll bar shows up just fine), and set a bottom-margin to these elements so that the very bottom of the element isn't flush with the very bottom of the window (a little space would be nice).

I have tried this on several elements just to see if it was only the one element (or the fact that it was out of the initial visible part of the window) that was giving me problems, but I can't seem to get any effect out of the margin property at all.

Looking here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229627.aspx  It seems that this is, indeed, what the margin property should do. Also, I can't find any padding within the GUI controls for any element.

As it stands, I am mostly only coding C# for the event handlers, until I get a better grasp of where Visual Studio puts everything within the two partial classes (and the other .cs files).

If it helps, here is the code for the designer file:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    partial class IntroForm
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
        this.WelcomeHeader = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.ActionSelect = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
        this.ProceedBtn = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.richTextBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // WelcomeHeader
        // 
        this.WelcomeHeader.AutoSize = true;
        this.WelcomeHeader.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 15.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.WelcomeHeader.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(84, 30);
        this.WelcomeHeader.Name = "WelcomeHeader";
        this.WelcomeHeader.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(367, 25);
        this.WelcomeHeader.TabIndex = 0;
        this.WelcomeHeader.Text = "Please Select Which Content You";
        // 
        // ActionSelect
        // 
        this.ActionSelect.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.WindowFrame;
        this.ActionSelect.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.ActionSelect.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
        "Events",
        "Headline News",
        "Images For Slideshow",
        "Agendas",
        "Job Opportunities",
        "Schedule Of Meetings",
        "Legal Notices",
        "Main Street (Main Link)",
        "Tourism (Main Link)",
        "Rental Properties",
        "Concert In The Park",
        "Main Street News Letters"});
        this.ActionSelect.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(126, 116);
        this.ActionSelect.Name = "ActionSelect";
        this.ActionSelect.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(283, 28);
        this.ActionSelect.TabIndex = 1;
        this.ActionSelect.Text = "Please Select";
        // 
        // ProceedBtn
        // 
        this.ProceedBtn.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ButtonFace;
        this.ProceedBtn.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Hand;
        this.ProceedBtn.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.DimGray;
        this.ProceedBtn.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(221, 192);
        this.ProceedBtn.Name = "ProceedBtn";
        this.ProceedBtn.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(93, 34);
        this.ProceedBtn.TabIndex = 2;
        this.ProceedBtn.Text = "Proceed";
        this.ProceedBtn.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
        this.ProceedBtn.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.ProceedBtn_Click);
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this.label1.AutoSize = true;
        this.label1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 15.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(142, 55);
        this.label1.Name = "label1";
        this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(251, 25);
        this.label1.TabIndex = 3;
        this.label1.Text = "Would Like To Change";
        // 
        // richTextBox1
        // 
        this.richTextBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(147, 268);
        this.richTextBox1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3, 3, 3, 30);
        this.richTextBox1.Name = "richTextBox1";
        this.richTextBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(246, 269);
        this.richTextBox1.TabIndex = 4;
        this.richTextBox1.Text = "";
        // 
        // IntroForm
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(9F, 20F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.AutoScroll = true;
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(0)))), ((int)(((byte)(102)))), ((int)(((byte)(0)))));
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(535, 306);
        this.Controls.Add(this.richTextBox1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.ProceedBtn);
        this.Controls.Add(this.ActionSelect);
        this.Controls.Add(this.WelcomeHeader);
        this.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(204)))), ((int)(((byte)(153)))), ((int)(((byte)(0)))));
        this.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4, 5, 4, 5);
        this.Name = "IntroForm";
        this.Text = "Okmulgee Online Web File Generator";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.Label WelcomeHeader;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox ActionSelect;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button ProceedBtn;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox richTextBox1;
}
}
```

------------------------------------------UPDATE-------------------------------------------

The element I have set the bottom margin property to within the code above is simply, richTextBox1.

Also, I did find a Padding element to the main form element, but sadly, this doesn't push other elements away from its edges either :(

What do these properties do (margin, padding)?

Comment: You forgot to set the form's AutoSize property to True.  Required to allow it to grow and provide the margin you requested.

Comment: @HansPassant Indeed, that worked. Care to make it an answer, so I can accept?  I thought I set that AutoSize property already. Before I set something (that I thought was this AutoSize property) to true, I wasn't even getting a vertical scrollbar, so I thought that that was what AutoSize did. Sorry, and thanks!

Comment: @HansPassant Anyway I can get both the scrollbar and margins to work initially?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Margin property is used by the automatic layout feature built into Winforms.  But it does require that you allow the container to grow so it can provide the requested margin.  So you must set the form's AutoSize property to True.

Combining AutoSize and AutoScroll is possible, you can set the MaximumSize property to prevent it from growing too much.  The scrollbar automatically appears when the layout calculation produces a layout that exceeds the MaximumSize.  The default maximum size is the Screen.WorkingArea on which the form is displayed, usually good enough.

Comment: Also, I thought I would mention that I had to end up making use of the AutoScrollMargin to get a little space at the bottom of the page when I wanted to start the window smaller than the contents of the form.